# How to construct an integer based on the binary input of 8 to 32 GPIO pins

Tags: microcontroller, parallel, gpio, binary

I'm researching a sensor for a project that has multiple methods of returning a value, one of them being a parallel output system that breaks down the value into 16 bit binary and transmits each bit on its own GPIO. There are other options for reading the data, but I'm curious and realized that I couldn't quite envision the code that would go into taking 8 to 32 (or beyond) binary numbers and converting them into a single integer. I feel like it should be pretty simple, but it keeps eluding me.

Does anyone have any examples, advice or resources they could point me to?

Comment: For what microcontroller?

Comment: I feel like you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how numbers are represented in digital systems. If your sensor is digital, then its value is already binary - there is no "breaking down" required in order to present that binary value on a parallel bus. Similarly, there (usually) is no code required for a digital system to read a parallel binary input and "convert it into an integer", because it already is one.

Comment: @brhans I think it's more a poor word choice on my part. I more meant "I've received a collection of ones and zeroes across x number of physical GPIO, how do I put all those ones and zeroes into a single variable"

Comment: @Rodo It'd be an STM32 in this case, though you could take your pick. I was more concerned in general with how to get x number of 1s and 0s from x number of GPIO and get them into a single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward.

If you have two 8-bit ports, with the high 8-bits on A, you can do:

```
x = (PORTA << 8) | PORTB;
```

If all of your pins are jumbled around, you might need to define something like:

```
#define DEVICE_BIT15 0x04   /* or wherever you put it */
...

x = 0;
if (PORTA & DEVICE_BIT15) { x |= 0x8000; }
if (PORTA & DEVICE_BIT14) { x |= 0x4000; }
...
if (PORTB & DEVICE_BIT0) { x |= 0x0001; }
```

Comment: Right, I think I remember learning something like this on a Zilog Z80Q (I think that's what it was). The experience was so bad I think I Eternal Sunshined it from my memory. I'm planning on doing this on an STM32 microcontroller, so I at least know how to narrow down my search. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parallel 16-bit (or any-bit) bus already represents an integer. So you only need to read the 16-bit bus bits, for example via 16-bit GPIO port, and you have the same 16 bits in an integer variable.

For example memory chips such as SRAM or Flash chips can have a 16-bit parallel bus.

Depends on what the sensor is and what data it really outputs and in which protocol, the MCU might have a peripheral designed to capture the bus for you (e.g. 16-bit parallel camera data interface).

Comment: In this case, it's a plane scanner, and I'm planning on using an STM32 microcontroller.

Comment: @E.HP.S That's fine, but you really can't receive anything unless you also get a clock signal or other framing signal or have a predefined timebase when to read in the data bits. Without more details, there is no way to know when to read the pins, like once per second, or thousand times, or million times, and when to start or stop.

Comment: Last I checked, it'd be on request. Like I said though, there's a few options for receiving the data and I realized this option was the one I had the least confidence in my understanding of how it works and wanted to correct that